# The GraphQL type name, defined in the ContentSchemaProvider schema provider, begins with a lower-case character. Types must be Pascal Cased

Tags: sitecore, scs

While setting up the Sitecore Content Serialization, I am facing this issue as the Type Name is in smaller case, needs to be in Pascal case

[image]

Tried checking the Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.Master.config, but did not find any type name
Any help will be appreciated.